# Can't execute terminal commands: "the command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo'"

Tags: command-line, 12.04

I have been using Ubuntu 12.04 for quite a while and have never had a problem come at me out of the blue like this. I'm trying to install python 3.2 on my Ubuntu system and every time I run the code to compile the python source, I get this error:

```
'Command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
sudo: command not found'
```

I've also tried running `gksudo` command to view what my environment shows but I pretty much get the same error.

Comment: I bet you'll probably get the same error when you try to run your applications through command line. What's the output of `cat /etc/environment`?

Comment: Could you tell us what program are you trying to execute? Some programs change the PATH variable, but without the name we couldn't be sure.

Answer (score 37):

As the error say, you should add `/usr/bin` directory to your PATH environment variable. To do this, run the following command in terminal:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
```

After you can use `sudo`, you can edit `/etc/environment` file to make the change permanent, so, run in terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/environment
```

to edit the file. Make sure that the path is something like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

Save and close the file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and press <kbd>Y</kbd> when you are asked.

See also: [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

Comment: This isn't permanent though, right? If he restarts, it'll go away again.

Comment: Yes. The permanent settings for your user are probably in `~/.profile`, `~/.bashrc`, `~/.pam_environment` or `~/.xsessionrc`. Settings for all users are probably in `/etc/profile`, `/etc/profile.d/*`, `/etc/environment`, `/etc/bash/bashrc`, `/etc/lightdm/xsession`. Probably one of your users files overrides the default system wide settings. If you have another user or the guest account enabled, try with the other user and see if the problem exists for that other user too. If not, check your own users startup script files.

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you very much! But, could you please add more information on how to make this change permanenr??? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

I got the problem and fixed it by editing my `.bashrc` file

1. Open up your `.bashrc` file using nano

   ```
   $ nano ~/.bashrc
   ```
2. Add the following line to the `.bashrc` file

   ```
   export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:   /usr/local/games"
   ```
3. Press Ctrl+X to save the file
4. It will ask to chnage the file, press <kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You're done.

Comment: Do not manipulate files in your home directory (`~`) using `sudo`. It can create more problems than it can solve.

Comment: @Melebius, like what problems?

Comment: @SirajAlam [This one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869336/firefox-only-runs-with-sudo), for example.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to add a new value to the `PATH` system variable, you most likely add a new line to `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` files.

For example, if you want to add `/opt/netbeans/bin` to `PATH`, you must add this line to the end of `~/.bashrc` file:

```bsh
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/netbeans/bin
```

**Let's break this line down.**

- `export PATH` - Here we refer to the `PATH` variable
- `=` - We want to assign it **a new value** using the `=` operator
       (The rest of the string is the value that will be stored in the `PATH`)
- `$PATH` - We assign the variable `PATH` to the value **that was in the variable before the current command**
- `:` - We add a separator for the new value
- `/opt/netbeans/bin` - And add a new value to the `PATH`

---

You must see all of your refers to the `PATH` variable in the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile` files and **make sure that you expand** -

```bsh
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/netbeans/bin
```

and **not** overwrite like this -

```bsh
export PATH=/opt/netbeans/bin
```

the `PATH` variable

**You must make sure, in every reference to the `PATH` you use `$PATH:` and your additional value after it**

---

If it doesn't work, you may do something like this:

- Make sure, there is something like the next variable in `/etc/environment` file and it never redefined in this file:

```bsh
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
```

- Add missing paths from the above `PATH` variable to your `PATH` variable located in the `/etc/environment`

---

**Before testing after each change in files don't remember to update your configs.**

For example for `~/.bashrc` file:

```bsh
source `~/.bashrc`
```

Comment: Thank you, I assumed I had overwritten the path and you confirmed it. Fixed login issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread but I got here following the same problem.
In my case I most likely accidently edited a line in the ~/.bashrc file.
By fixing the following line to appear as in the picture it solved my problem:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3vq0.png
(mine had the ':' in the wrong place).

I don't think there is a need to add a line, just make sure the line with the PATH is correct(unless you also have your own scripts saved somewhere).

In order to get to the ~/.bashrc you can either use graphical methods (make sure to show hidden files) and go to the home folder.
OR -
use
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
to enable some commands temporarily as was suggested here earlier, then open ~/.bashrc using

```
nano ~./bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PATH variable has been messed up. You have to add /usr/bin in $PATH.
To corect that,run the following command on the terminal.

`export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH`

However the command above works only in the current session,when you log off and login bac you will land in the same error. Parmenently set PATH by running the following command

```
echo "PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: This is a dupe of a answer already given.