# The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable

Tags: sudo

Can someone tell me why I get this error when I try to add a repository and what if anything I can do about it?

When I try to add a repository using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:upubuntu-com/tor
```

I get the following error:

```
Command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH      
environment variable.
sudo: command not found
```

Comment: I've solve this issue by following way : Check here... https://askubuntu.com/a/1318368/1185282

Answer (score 68):

Your PATH variable has been messed up.  Unless you are trying to run a restricted user with `rbash`, you should have /usr/bin in `$PATH`.  For a terminal session you can fix this by running:

```
export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

As @SylvainPineau mentioned, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/338728/267266) covers how to permanently fix your path by editing the `/etc/environment` file.

Comment: or export PATH="/usr/sbin:$PATH"

Comment: This worked for me.
/usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/nano ~/.bashrc

export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin"