# My $PATH variable is messed up. How to change it back?

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, paths

Whenever I try basic commands in the terminal like `sudo` or `ls`, I get this error:

> Command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo' The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
>   sudo: command not found

When I type in `echo $PATH`, it returns

> /Downloads/stata installation/stata15:/Downloads/stata

I suspect I messed up the `$PATH` variable when trying to install Stata.

I've tried `export PATH="/usr/bin:$PATH"` which fixes the problem temporarily (from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452488/the-command-could-not-be-located-because-usr-bin-is-not-included-in-the-path)). Then when I do `echo $PATH`, it returns

> /usr/bin:/Downloads/stata installation/stata15:/Downloads/stata

But this fix is temporary and when I restart the terminal, I can't use sudo again.

---

[This other answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338726/cant-execute-terminal-commands-the-command-sudo-is-available-in-usr-bin-s) says that I can make a permanent fix:

First, I did `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin`, and which again fixes the problem temporarily. When I do `echo $PATH`, it returns

> /Downloads/stata installation/stata15:/Downloads/stata:/usr/bin

Then I'm supposed to be able to make it permanent by editing the `/etc/environment` file with `sudo nano /etc/environment` and making sure that it is

> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

When I open the `/etc/environment` file, it already has that exact path, so nothing is changed. So when I restart the terminal, basic commands like `sudo` still doesn't work and I have to do the temporary fix again.

I suspect that the `/etc/environment` file is not the issue and there is another file that I need to change. Do you happen to know how to fix it?

Comment: Thank you, it does look like this is the problem. At the bottom of the `/home/$USER/.bashrc` file I have 

`export PATH=/Downloads/stata\ installation/stata:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/s$

export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/$

export PATH=/Downloads/stata\ installation/stata15:/Downloads/stata installation/stata$`

Should I reduce all 3 lines down to 
`export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/$`?

Comment: That worked perfectly after I restarted the terminal. I deleted the part about Stata since I don't have it installed properly. Yes, please write a full answer and I will accept it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to permanently change `$PATH` variable?

A similar question has been answered before at [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path)

### Where to make the change?

$PATH can be changed at various levels and for various situations. At the global level the $PATH is stored in `/etc/environment`. Changing this will alter the default $PATH set for all the users of the computer.

Personalized custom changes can be done in three places based on one's need.

1. To change the path of all login sessions change the path at `/home/$USER/.profile`.
2. To change the in bash shell sessions that are opened after login, such as the terminal window, change the path at `/home/$USER/.bashrc`.
3. To change the in GUI sessions that may be opened after login, such as a remote GUI shell, change the path at `/home/$USER/.xsessionrc`.

### How to make the change?

Typically you add a new PATH statement or an export command like:

```
PATH="/path/to/dir:$PATH"
```

or

```
export PATH="/path/to/dir:$PATH"
```

Note these statements use the $PATH variable on the right hand side. This specific way off adding a new directory to the $PATH adds the new directory at the **beginning** of the existing $PATH variable.

## Specific Case in the Question

Look for the files mentioned above:

- `/etc/environment`
- `/home/$USER/.profile`
- `/home/$USER/.bashrc`
- `/home/$USER/.xsessionrc`

to find exactly where the $PATH was modified by the improper installation of the software *Stata*. In this case modifications where made in `/home/$USER/.bashrc`.

From the comments, three `export` statements were added to `/home/$USER/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH=/Downloads/stata\ installation/stata:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
export PATH=/Downloads/stata\ installation/stata15:/Downloads/stata installation/stata
```

The first `export` statement adds the `/Downloads/stata\ installation/stata` in the beginning of the default $PATH.
The second `export` statement resets the $PATH to the default set for directories.
The second `export` statement tries set the $PATH to some Stata directories but misses the escape character `\` before the space and messes up the `/Downloads/stata installation/stata` as only `/Downloads/stata`

Since Stata is not installed in this computer you don't need any of these modifications. You can comment all the export statements as:

```
#export PATH=/Downloads/stata\ installation/stata:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
#export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
#export PATH=/Downloads/stata\ installation/stata15:/Downloads/stata installation/stata
```

Note inserting the `#` in the beginning of each line marks them as comments. If everything works after commenting these `export` commands, you may delete them from the `.bashrc` file.

Commenting out or deleting these three lines will your bash session without these customization of $PATH variables. You will be using the defaults set in `/etc/environment`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Great answer! Thank you very much!