# The command could not be located because '/bin'

Tags: command-line

Something is going really wrong with my cmd.
I am trying to run a simple 'ls' command and it is impossible.
The error says

```
Command 'ls' is available in '/bin/ls The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.'
```

I tried to find similar question but I didn't managed to fix the problem, and I am afraid that I will make it worse.
When I run

```
echo $PATH
```

I am getting this

```
bash: SPATH:/home/george/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin:/opt/netbeans/bin: No such file or directory
```

I think I messed it up with flutter and netbeans but I am not sure how to fix it.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4):

Your PATH environmental variable does not anymore include standard system locations for binaries. `ls`, which is an executable in `/usr/bin/`, is not found. `echo` is a shell build-in and thus can be executed.

Your error is caused by a typo. You indicated `SPATH` rather than `$PATH` in your new PATH statement. The first is just that, the second will be substituted automatically by the current setting of the PATH.

So wherever you changed your PATH, correct this typo. Chances are you have done the changes in `~/.profile` or eventually `~/.bashrc`, unless you have modified system files. [See here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1161740/my-path-variable-is-messed-up-how-to-change-it-back) for places where a PATH is set or changed in a Linux system.

Answer (score 2):

There's probably a typo in your integration of Flutter and NetBeans. If you reference a environment variable, you prefix it with a dollar sign, for example `$PATH`.

To add something to your existing path, you set the variable to the old value, plus your additions:

```
PATH="$PATH:/some/other/directory"
```

Going by your question, your integration of Flutter and NetBeans doesn't refer to `$PATH`, but to `SPATH`. So, you're setting the path to the newly added directories, but without keeping the previous path.