# Whenever i execute a command it says: Command 'name of command i am trying to run' is available in the following places:

Tags: command-line, bash

Whenever I type neofetch, i get this error:

```
Command 'neofetch' is available in the following places
 * /bin/neofetch
 * /usr/bin/neofetch
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
neofetch: command not found
```

This also happens to a lot of other commands that I run.
Here is what happens when I run echo $PATH:

```
$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: There is a problem with your PATH environment variable. Have you modified it manually, or maybe installed or run some program, that has modified it? Maybe anaconda? Please try to remember what you have installed or run recently. You can also run `echo $PATH` and edit your original question to show the resuilt, your current PATH.

Comment: Somehow, the directories that are typically listed in your `PATH` variable aren't listed anymore. We recently [had a similar case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1373067/the-command-could-not-be-located-because-bin) where a typo in a line to extend the `PATH` probably was the cause. Maybe it's a similar cause in your case.

Comment: ok i edited my question.

Comment: Have you modified PATH manually, or maybe installed or run some program, that has modified it? Maybe anaconda?

Comment: I think thats what happened.

Comment: I checked .bashrc and .profile and did not see any typos with path. Anything that said path in either of those files said $PATH

Comment: You must remember that upper case and lower case letters are **different** in Linux, so you should run `echo $PATH`. Maybe you set it literally (within single quotes), so that it is not expanded. In my computer it is `/home/sudodus/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/games` (one line)

Comment: sorry that was a typo. I actually did type $PATH.

Comment: Is there anything i can do?

Comment: Did you maybe copy & paste some lines that change the `PATH`? I've seen cases where people copied some stuff in and wound up with [curly quotes](https://typographyforlawyers.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html). Maybe the line that adds `$HOME/.local/bin` was printed with a similar glyph replacing `$` where you copied it from.

Comment: Also, Zorin maybe based on Ubuntu, but it isn't an official Ubuntu flavour. Therefore, I'm afraid this question is probably [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) here and will probably be closed. If you can't solve the rest of your problem on your own, [Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [the Zorin forums](https://forum.zorin.com/) maybe a good place.

Comment: Thanks :-) Anyway, you are missing a lot of directories, where there are executable programs (you may not need those for games, but the others are pretty standard).

Comment: I think i did run a command that did have something to do with my path. Is there anything i can do to fix this?

Comment: You should try to find out where and how the error was introduced and avoid it in the future. And of course reset PATH to a reasonable value in a persistent way. We don't know the details of Zorin, it may differ from Ubuntu, so you had better ask for details at a Zorin forum.

Comment: I got the answer on the Zorin forum, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue use this command in terminal

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
```

Comment: yes, that worked. Thanks.

Comment: actually a better way would be to add this command at the bottom of .bashrc