# I screwed up my system no commands work at all

Tags: command-line, bash, gcc

```
Command 'make' is available in '/usr/bin/make'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the 
PATH environment variable.
make: command not found
```

It happened after I did this:

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1/:$PATH
```

After I copied and paste it it automatically executed in the terminal after realizing my mistake I corrected like this below.

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1/bin:$PATH
```

It isn't just make:

```
Command 'whoami' is available in '/usr/bin/whoami' The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
whoami: command not found
```

Comment: okay, so by all commands you mean "only make commands"?

Comment: No most important commands like ls

Comment: aa-status, apt-get, whoami,

Comment: >root@ubuntu:~/Downloads/NOOKPROJECT/nook2kernelsrc/distro>/kernel# whoami
Command 'whoami' is available in '/usr/bin/whoami'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
whoami: command not found

Comment: possible duplicate of [Won't execute terminal commands](http://askubuntu.com/questions/338726/wont-execute-terminal-commands)

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `echo $PATH`. `echo` is a shell built-in comand.

Comment: It improved my situation but aa-status only works in root if I use like su or sudo su

Comment: /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games. echo

Comment: If you just ran the `export` command in a terminal then it will only affect that terminal (shell) - just open another one (Ctrl-Alt-t, or from the dash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the folders where commands can be found in the PATH environment variable. So it sounds like your PATH environment variable is missing the `/usr/bin` entry. What is the output of `echo $PATH` for your system?

The default for Ubuntu 14.04 is  `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games` and you can restore this by simply running

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

Then you should be able run the command you tried in the first place to add the paths, or to add them all at once you can simply run...

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export PATH+=:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/cc1/bin
```

Also, you should consider adding it to `.bashrc` if you want to make it a part of `$PATH` every time you open a terminal.