# Upgraded Ubuntu 15.04 and its going into login loop after that

Tags: 15.04, login, password

Have tried other solutions posted on AU
I tried <kbd>CLTR</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.
It takes me to the login screen command screen. I logged in using UN & PW
After that I tried many commands posted in other solutions but it gives me command not found in bin.

Right now my terminal looks like :

```
shivam@shivam-Lenovo-ideapas-300-15ISK:~$
```

And its not taking any command here.

Can anyone help me with the same.

TIA

Comment: What do you mean it's not taking any command? If there is an error, please post the error, thanks.

Comment: Command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo/'      The comman could not be located because 'usr'bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.    sudo: command not found

Comment: Then follow my instructions to receive a root prompt from the recovery menu accessed from grub.

Comment: Also, see here http://askubuntu.com/questions/338726/wont-execute-terminal-commands

Comment: Also, 15.04 is no longer supported and you need to upgrade to a supported version. The command I have listed below should upgrade you to a supported version. If not, you may have to reinstall. If you reinstall, you should probably reinstall using 16.04 or newer. Don't forget to make a backup of your files.

Comment: Sure, I'll update it. Moreover I think the above link solution will work but currently stuck with the recovery command, I mean they are still loading. I'll update you in sometime. Thanks

Comment: do-release-upgrade should do the upgrade for you if you make it that far.

Comment: do-release-upgrade gave me, No new release found. I tried it without enabling networking as it got stuck with I did that and I had to restart.

Comment: got stuck on grep: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory

Comment: Choose the with networking option, then choose fix broken packages and then follow these instructions http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release You do not need to use sudo when working from a root prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing the recovery options from the grub menu.

First, choose the "with networking" option. Then, choose the option to fix broken packages. This should mount the drive in read write mode. Then, choose a root prompt and execute the following command:

```
do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: The issue was with the username, that worked but no command is working now. Have updated my question.

Comment: So basically I'm able to run SUDO there and command(various commands mentioned in many solutions) are also not giving any errors, but still stuck in login loop.

Comment: As I suppose that you're not stuck in a log-in loop on the recovery console, please open a new question if you have a new question.