# Can open thunderbird only as root (e.g. with sudo) to have access to my user profile? How do I regain my rights again?

Tags: permissions, sudo, thunderbird

I can only access my `thunderbird` profile, when using `sudo` in the terminal - otherwise I only can access the profile launcher and then I can't open the profiles, which are linked from there on.

(Trying to open `thunderbird` as non-root via terminal doesn't give any indication where the problem could be, it simply exits without any description why).

How do I regain my access rights?

Edit:

```
username@username:~$ ls -lsa ~/.thunder*
insgesamt 28
4 drwxr-xr-x  6 username username 4096 Jan 18 09:59 .
4 drwxr-xr-x 35 username username 4096 Feb  6 01:24 ..
4 drwxr-xr-x 11 username username 4096 Feb 13 12:40 4m8yzmic.default
4 drwxr-xr-x  4 username username 4096 Jan 30 13:01 Crash Reports
4 -rwxr-xr-x  1 username username  157 Feb 13 12:40 profiles.ini
4 drwxr-xr-x 23 username username 4096 Feb  7 16:58 psw1ez3h.default
4 drwxr-xr-x  2 username username 4096 Feb  6 01:05 qlyave08.default

username@username:~$ ls -lsa ~/.mozi*
insgesamt 16
4 drwx------  4 username username 4096 Jan  6 20:33 .
4 drwxr-xr-x 35 username username 4096 Feb  6 01:24 ..
4 drwx------  3 username username 4096 Jan  8 17:36 extensions
4 drwx------ 13 username username 4096 Jan  8 17:36 firefox
```

---

Edit 2 :

```
username@username:chmod -R 755 ~/.moz* 
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/datareporting/session-state.json': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/datareporting/aborted-session-ping': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/datareporting/archived/2017-02/1486968065960.896dcf18-aa5b-49c3-8773-009937b4fd70.main.jsonlz4': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/datareporting/archived/2017-02/1486968697830.1c570bc8-8815-44a1-b65e-cddb285b2985.main.jsonlz4': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/datareporting/archived/2017-02/1486557781286.02f8d55e-2070-410f-8893-b124693d19d2.main.jsonlz4': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/datareporting/archived/2017-01/1484262000031.b86e5aa5-e33c-48c2-b319-7ee5d74cf437.main.jsonlz4': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/datareporting/archived/2017-01/1485345072158.02847fd6-7195-4534-8b84-af12f710820c.main.jsonlz4': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/datareporting/archived/2017-01/1484322845561.3efc919d-3ed7-4454-9d0d-85ef3b40ecdf.main.jsonlz4': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/datareporting/archived/2017-01/1485386831718.6a28907a-e8d6-452d-8ba9-ee67cac2b753.main.jsonlz4': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/prefs.js': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/extensions.json': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/blocklist.xml': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/sessionCheckpoints.json': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/saved-telemetry-pings/02847fd6-7195-4534-8b84-af12f710820c': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/crashes/store.json.mozlz4': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/addons.json': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/notificationstore.json': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/zotero.sqlite.1.bak': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/pipes/1486456509721': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/zotero/zotero.sqlite.bak': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/bookmarkbackups/bookmarks-2017-02-08_6818_6d2f7uXbf9JRu9a7l8qAcQ==.jsonlz4': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/bookmarkbackups/bookmarks-2017-02-13_6819_AvGyzC3aHz5A4zQVqX7M0w==.jsonlz4': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.bak': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.js': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/xulstore.json': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/search.json.mozlz4': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/extensions/firefox@ghostery.com.xpi': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/extensions/staged': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: das Verzeichnis '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/extensions/staged' kann nicht gelesen werden: Keine Berechtigung
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/extensions/@mendeleyimporter.xpi': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/addonsreconciler.json': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/changes/addons.json': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/changes/history.json': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/changes/forms.json': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/changes/bookmarks.json': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1486456524713.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1486985946185.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1487006015650.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1486498318875.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1487002409350.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1486982340079.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1486483895455.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1486978733685.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1486491108784.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1486995198810.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1486998803430.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1486487502524.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1486975128774.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1487013226932.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1486968612053.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1486501923932.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1486494713222.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1486991593728.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/weave/logs/error-sync-1487009621799.txt': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/mwad0hks.default/blocklist-plugins.json': Vorgang nicht zulässig
chmod: Beim Setzen der Zugriffsrechte für '/home/username/.mozilla/firefox/Crash Reports/InstallTime20170201180315': Vorgang nicht zulässig
```

`username@username:~$ sudo chown -R username:username ~username/.thunderbird chmod -R 755 ~/.thunderbird
chown: Zugriff auf 'chmod' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
chown: Zugriff auf '755' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
username@username:~$ sudo chown -R username:username /home/username/.thunderbird
username@username:~$ sudo chmod -R 775 /home/username/.thunderbird
username@username:~$ thunderbird
username@username:~$`

Comment: Similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/869336/firefox-only-runs-with-sudo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the description in the link and the code from Yaron, I could solve the problem with

`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.thunder*`

Big thanks to all people who participated in solving my issue esp. @Melebius and @Yaron!
Great support! If somebody knows, how to efficially link the answer to the linkedsolution in the thread given by @Melebius, feel free to do so.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like your files are not owned by you, or have wrong permission.

Please execute the following command to make sure that you have the right access permission on `~/.mozilla-thunderbird` folder:

```
chmod -R 755 ~/.mozilla-thunderbird
```

If you still have problems accessing other folders - you can change the folder owner to be your-user-name using:

```
sudo chown -R your_user_name:your_group_name /your_folder
```

`chown -R` - recursive update the owner of  `/your_folder` to be `your_user_name and your_group_name`

For example (please replace `your_user_name` with your user name) :

```
sudo chown -R your_user_name:your_group_name ~your_user_name/.mozilla-thunderbird
```

**Edit: After your last edit it seems like your `thunderbird` is located in  `~/.thunderbird`**

Can you please execute the following commands (please close `thunderbird` before running those commands):

```
sudo chown -R your_user_name:your_group_name ~your_user_name/.thunder*
chmod -R 755 ~/.thunderbird
```

Those commands should make sure that the ~/.thunderbird folder is own by you, and have the right permissions.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. There is only /.thunderbird though - first command seems not to be valid in my case (sth like access denied = "Vorgang nicht zulässig") - second command brings no results. Can I use my "username" as group-variable? used command "groups" in terminal  `username@username-H61MA-D3V:~$ groups
username adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare`

Comment: I used my username as group in the context of the commands as my user appeared to be in this group.

Comment: please share result of execution `ls -lsa ~/.mozi*` and `ls -lsa ~/.thunder*`

Comment: Shared the results via edit.

Comment: Please excute chmod -R 755 ~/.moz*

Comment: Edited results under Edit 2.

Comment: Still interested in a solution if anybody wants to contribute.

Comment: @Bogotrax - please try the suggestion in my edit

Comment: @Melebius thanks for your kind note, I've update my answer

Comment: thanks for going through this with me. Edit 3 shows the result from your recommandation