# changing rights of /.gvfs not implemented. How to resolve it?

Tags: mount

tried the following commands from the link to regain access rights of my userfolder

> You can verify this with:
>
> ```
> $ find ~/ -mount ! -user $(whoami)
> ```
>
> You can correct this with:
>
> ```
> $ sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) ~/
> ```

And I get the results:

```
username@username:~$ find ~/ -mount ! -user $(whoami)
find: "/home/username/.gvfs": Keine Berechtigung
/home/username/.gvfs
username@username:~$ sudo chown -R $(whoami):$(whoami) ~/
chown: der Eigentümer von '/home/username/.gvfs' wird geändert: Die angeforderte Funktion ist nicht implementiert
```

How can I resolve the issue?

---

Similar: [Firefox only runs with `sudo`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/869336/firefox-only-runs-with-sudo)

Comment: If that is the actual result your firefox problem is NOT due to permissions of your profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `find ~/ -mount ! -user $(whoami)` requires `sudo so ...

   ```
   sudo find ~/ -mount ! -user $(whoami)
   ```
2. `.gvfs` needs to be owned by root so the notice is correct. The command though should not be run like that. Please follow the other answer https://askubuntu.com/a/876022/15811 if you only have problems with firefox.

---

Regarding 1:

```
$ find . -mount ! -user $USER
./.gvfs
find: `./.gvfs': Permission denied
./.config/enchant
find: `./.config/enchant': Permission denied
./.dbus
find: `./.dbus': Permission denied
./.cache/dconf
find: `./.cache/dconf': Permission denied

~$ sudo find . -mount ! -user $USER
./.gvfs
./.config/enchant
./.config/enchant/en_US.exc
./.config/enchant/en_US.dic
./.dbus
./.dbus/session-bus
./.dbus/session-bus/b9a307ab19d1c2845bf0bf9854f87478-0
./.cache/dconf
```

This is normal and should not be changed. If you see any other directories (and in your case that would be `.mozilla` you can change the owner and user with the 2nd command but I would then not do it on your home but the actual directory).

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! As I have problems with plenty of programs I would love to use the given solution in the right way. Is there a right way to do it similarly to the code in my initial post?

Comment: do the 1st command. If the results are similar to my edit your problem is not permissions for your profile. For that you would need to see a result that includes `./mozilla` since your profile is in there.

Comment: Thanks, the result included ./mozilla and I resolved it using                                     `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER ~/.mozilla`

Comment: good! have an upvote ;)