# Ubuntu login loop due to path variable

Tags: login

recently I messed up my PATH in environment variables,  and now I can't go past the login loop. Is there a  way to fix it from the shell?

Regards

Rahul

Happy to provide more info.

Comment: How / where did you mess up `PATH` (what file(s) did you modify?). Can you log in at one of the CLI virtual terminals (Ctrl-Alt-F1 thru Ctrl-Alt-F6)?

Comment: You'll soon realise I'm very new to linux... but I updated bash profile... added a path for android sdk as I was playing with nativescript...

Comment: And yes I was able to login to ctrl Alt F3

Comment: In that case, revert your bash profile changes from there using any available  CLI editor such as `nano` or `vim`

Comment: Okay I'll try which is the best way to learn the new os too but incase I can't,  could I please bother you to guide me through it?

Comment: Thanks man. Worked!!! Really appreciate that. Also followed these steps https://askubuntu.com/questions/338726/wont-execute-terminal-commands/338728#338728 and now I can login.