# error installing ruby

Tags: command-line, ruby

I am getting this error:

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install build-essential git zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev libpq-dev \ 
       libssl-dev libreadline-dev libsodium-dev file

Command 'sudo' is available in the following places:

 * /bin/sudo
 * /usr/bin/sudo

The command could not be located because '/bin:/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.

sudo: command not found
```

Comment: So you messed up your `PATH` somehow - see [Can't execute terminal commands: "the command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo'"](https://askubuntu.com/a/338728/178692)

Comment: Hello. Try something simple first to verify sudo is being found and working. sudo nano